# How convert timestamp and put in a <input type="date">?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable that contains timestamp value that I have calculated first. I need to convert timestamp variable in a date and put the date in my:

```
<input type="date" id="topic_date">
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: you have to try something first.
If you want to do this you have to create a Date object with your timestamp, get a string with this format: YYYY-MM-DD (thanks to your new date object) and give that string to your input

Comment: I couldn't understand your question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, parsing the timestamp into a date object first, after converting to milliseconds from seconds:

```
function lpad(str, length) {
    var lengthDiff = length - str.length;
    while(lengthDiff > 0) {
        str = '0' + str;
        lengthDiff--;
    }
    return str;
}

var parsedTimestamp = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
document.getElementById('topic_date').value = parsedTimestamp.getFullYear() + '-' + lpad(parsedTimestamp.getMonth(), 2) + '-' + lpad(parsedTimestamp.getDate(), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetime doesn't work for me on chrome, datetime-local allows me to choose date and time from popup.

example

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="xyz" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",time()); ?>"/>
```

time() functions is not relevant ,I am using it to make it easy for user to choose from current.. time after or before.

Answer (score 0):

@jedifans We can use padStart() to format the number. And the month value starts from 0, so we should add 1 to the month value. The full code is like below:

```
const lpad2 = (number) => String(number).padStart(2, "0")
function timeStampToDate(timestamp) {
  let date = new Date(timestamp * 1000)
  return (
    date.getFullYear() + "-" + lpad2(date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + lpad2(date.getDate())
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider extending the Number object

```
if (!Number.prototype.epochToTime) {
  Number.prototype.epochToTime = function() {
    const time = (this * 1000);
    function pad(n) {
      return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
    }
    const date = new Date(time);
    return `${pad(date.getHours())}:${pad(date.getMinutes())}`; 
  };
}
```